# Ansible is skipping the debug line

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have this task in a **role** and a debug line beneath it:

```
- name: Restore bootstrap DB
  command: "mongorestore -v --host localhost:{{ mongodb_net.port }} -d {{ item.dbname }} --dir {{ item.clone_dir }}"
  register: restore_result
  with_items:
    - { dbname: "{{ mongodb_db1_dbname }}", clone_dir: "/var/tmp/db_bootstrap/DB1_CLONE" }
    - { dbname: "{{ mongodb_db2_dbname }}", clone_dir: "/var/tmp/db_bootstrap/DB2_CLONE" }

- debug: var=restore_result verbosity=2
```

But it's skipping the debug task.

```
TASK [mongodb : Restore bootstrap DB] ***************************************************
changed: [xx.xx.xx.167] => (item={u'dbname': u'DB1', u'clone_dir': u'/var/tmp/db_bootstrap/DB1'})
changed: [xx.xx.xx.167] => (item={u'dbname': u'DB2', u'clone_dir': u'/var/tmp/db_bootstrap/DB2'})

TASK [mongodb : debug] ******************************************************************
skipping: [xx.xx.xx.167]
```

When I enable verbose mode, `-vv`, it shows the content of the registered variable.

I'm using Ansible version **2.4.3**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's a missing feature in **2.4.3** which doesn't show the skip reason, this was added in **2.6.1**; Upgraded my version to **2.6.1** and saw the reason:

```
TASK [mongodb : debug] ********************************************************************************
skipping: [xx.xx.xx.167] => {"skipped_reason": "Verbosity threshold not met."}
```

So I removed the `verbosity=2` from the task and it's now working as expected.

Comment: drove me nuts. had exactly the same issue. removed verbosity line and started to work as expected

Comment: `verbosity=2` was the problem for me as well. I removed that and it stopped skipping the task.